How to choose base case for substitution method for solving recurrences?
I tried to find out how to solve recurrences using substitution method, but I don't understand: how is the base case chosen when the base case is not given explicitly?

I have two problems:

T(n) = 2T(floor(n/2)) + Θ(n) where the base cases are when the n = 2 or 3.
T(n) = T(n-1) + n with no apparent base case given.

For problem 2, I am not sure though but I researched online and found out that the base case should be 1.
So far what I have understood is the base case is the input size where there is no recursion, so for the first example given, why isn't the n=1 a base case since it does not involve recursion as well?


For problem 2, 
[...] 
why isn't the n=1 a base case since it does not involve recursion as well?

In the context of programming, n in Problem (2) is your input size (so don't worry about decreasing recursively to infinite negatives). If no explicit base case is given in the recurrence relation (which is in fact a translation of a recursive function in code) and your input size is decreasing for every subsequent call, then your base case is zero by default. This means your function has no input left to process, therefore, no work is done. This is equivalent to returning Null or 0 (to prevent type evaluation issues) without performing any significant operations.
If you apply substitution method in determining the bounds for T(n) = T(n - 1) + n, you will eventually arrive at the following kth term:
[k]:    T(n) = T(n - k) + n - (k - 1) + n - (k - 2) + ... + n - (k - k)
At some point (the default base case), there is no input to process anymore, i.e. T([n - k] = 0) which returns 0.
If n - k = 0; then k = n. Then substitute n for k in [k] to determine the bounds of T(n):
[k]:    T(n) = 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n
Therefore, T(n) is nothing but the sum of n natural numbers i.e. n(n+1)/2.
Hence, T(n) is O(n2).
Q.E.D.
